# Automatically redirect from old host to new host while preserving links

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, redirect

My employer purchased a new domain name and he want everything from the old domain to be redirected to the new domain. He said it should be a 301 redirect so that the search engine rankings will be retained.

So from http://olddomain.com/article-title should be (301) redirected to http://newdomain.com/article-title , keeping article-title the same all long (just the host name will be changed)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the htaccess file in `olddomain.com`'s document root, add:

```
Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com/
```

Or if you prefer using mod_rewrite, or if olddomain.com is actually hosting several different hosts:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Second one will work , I think, because it will preserve the segments after the host name.. thanks a lot!

Comment: @r2b2 The first one will do that as well, `Redirect` just links the path nodes so whatever comes after `/` gets passed onto `http://newdomain.com/`

Comment: so those two are virtually the same?

Comment: @r2b2 yeah, just different modules (mod_alias vs mod_rewrite). Mod rewrite is more flexible.